# Usability Heuristics - any other Heuristic studies other than Jakob's 10 Heuristics?

Tags: usability-testing, usability-study, heuristics

Whenever I look up to usability analysis examples and case studies I see these are done around the 10 Usability Heuristics by Jakob from NN group.

I am reaching out to the community if anybody has any references for any other study as done by NN group on Heurisitcs.

Answer (score 1):

While I asked this question to the community, I did research on my own.

I was able to find reference and material to this topic on medium in a reliable blog.

Here is the link to it
https://uxdesign.cc/usability-heuristic-frameworks-which-one-is-right-for-you-1962387b7cc

I would want to summarise the blog here. But it looks like it is a good place to stop by and go through the entire article that has good amount of useful information related to choosing of Heuristic framework according to the need.

Comment: It would be great if those heuristics were displayed on an actual website, something like this one https://keepsimple.io/uxcore

Comment: Wow this is crazy. Thank you for sharing this.